# Gstreamer Mac OS install bad plugin

Tags: macos, plugins, gstreamer

I've installed GStreamer SDK for mac os by this tutorial 
[Gstreamer SDK](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X)

But now i need to add a bad plugin in order to work with h264 video

And the question is how i can add bad plugin to framework - based Gstreamer installation?

Comment: do you have a good plugin instead?

Comment: actually i'm not sure if i have any of plugins

Comment: ok - i've got an idea - to use an homebrew installation of Gstreamer and to write the make file with path to gstreamer and it plugins
Can any one tell me the right way to write a make file to gstreamer?

Answer (score 0):

The GStreamer SDK installer for OSX doesn't not install by default plugins with patents issues.

When you launch the installer, make sure you select all the available features in the list to be installed, in particular the FFmpeg one, which provides the H264 decoder you need.